# Overflow is not working on hover

Tags: css, overflow

I want to place a image, title, some text in particular box and that box will be rounded. The box has background color with opacity by RGBA color. When the box is hovered then overflow is not working. I have following html structure:

```
<article id="post-181" class="post-181 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="#">A PARADISEMATIC COUNTRY</a></h2>
        <div class="post-info">
            <p>Posted by <a href="#">admin</a> on April 25, 2013</p>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <img width="270" height="208" src="http://roi.me/files/google-vs.-bing.jpg" class="alignright wp-post-image" alt="logos mini">
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</article>
```

and css is :

```
.post { 
margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 20px; width: 270px; height: 270px; margin-right: 30px; background: rgba(49, 187, 183, 0.5); border-radius: 50%; cursor: pointer; overflow: hidden; position: relative; -webkit-transition: .5s ease background;
}

.post .entry-content img {
position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; min-height: 270px; min-width: 270px; margin: 0; z-index: -100; border: 1px solid red;
}

.post:hover {
background: rgba(49, 187, 183, 1);
}
```

I already uploaded to jsfiddle:

[**Demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/itskawsar/42yPY/3/)

**Note:** i have tried with firefox and chrome. Firefox shows good but chrome cannot!

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you expect that to work?

Comment: Can you describe *overflow is not working* in more detail?

Comment: Your question is not clear. As I guess when user will hover over the circle you want a transparent color. If I am right then your code is ok only. just you have to use 0.5 or .5 instead of 1 in rgba value.

Comment: please check the demo in fiddle. First look is great. But when i hovered the box, all the element is coming out of that box. @Nelson

Comment: i also need to know what is the problem. please help me to know. @Mr.Alien

Comment: please check my previous comments.

Comment: @itskawsar Works fine on firefox, which browser are you talking about? please don't say IE

Comment: sorry! im testing on chrome. @Mr.Alien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on this tutorial:

[HOVER AND CLICK TRIGGER FOR CIRCULAR ELEMENTS WITH JQUERY](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/22/hover-and-click-trigger-circular-elements/)

Here is the [DEMO](http://tympanus.net/TipsTricks/HoverClickTriggerCircle/)

However, you'll have to use some jQuery to make it work.

Hope it helps

---

**EDIT**

If you don't want to use jQuery, then take a look on this tutorial:

[CIRCLE HOVER EFFECTS WITH CSS TRANSITIONS](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/08/circle-hover-effects-with-css-transitions/)

See the [DEMO](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircleHoverEffects/).

That way you don't need jQuery or JS, just CSS3 transitions.

Now I think that is what you want.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: i can do it with jquery but i want to do it with css3 transition effect.

Comment: Take a look on the second demo.